# Reference request for studying bilinear form.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, bilinear-form

I am a graduate student of Mathematics and I am in $1$st year of MSc.In our linear algebra course we have bilinear forms.But our instructor is not so good at teaching.So,I have to self-study the topic.What I am looking for is a good reference book for studying bilinear forms.I want a book that is for beginners.Can someone help me find one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These notes by Keith Conrad are very handy: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/bilinearform.pdf

Also, check out Artin's *Algebra*, Chapter 8 is on bilinear forms.

Comment: the notes are not suitable for me.However Artin is fine